# Results concerning surjectivity of Brauer groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, brauer-groups

Are there known cases of a morphism of smooth geometrically connected curves $f: X \rightarrow Y$ over a number field $k$ (to be specific) that would give rise to a surjective restriction map $f^*:\mathrm{Br}\, Y \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}\,X$?

One example (though not between two curves) is when $C$ is a smooth projective curve of genus $\geq 2$ with a rational point and $J$ is the Jacobian variety of $C$ with closed immersion $i: C \hookrightarrow J$. It can be shown that the restriction map $i^*$ of Brauer groups is indeed surjective.

I'm asking this because there've been a variety of results involving injectivity of the restriction map (purity theorems, embedding into Brauer group of function field, etc) but I cannot recall seeing even a few about surjectivity.

Comment: If the genus of both curves equals zero (and I suspect that is the only case).

Comment: @JasonStarr May I know how do you construct an example? Do you need the fact that its function field is the function field of $\mathbb{P}^1$ (which is $k(x)$), or something similar? My thought is to use the exact sequence of Milne's EC Example 2.22(a).